# C# return a single list into nested JSON API

Tags: c#, json, api, linq, model-view-controller

I have a simple list which is returned from my DB to my MVC API, the sample query is

```
select school, class, pupil from area
```

With that I am adding to a list

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var area = new Area();
    area.school = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
    area.class = row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
    area.pupil = row.ItemArray[2].ToString();
    returnedlist.Add(area);
}
```

at the moment the API just returns the list

```
{
  "School": "",
  "Class": "",
  "Pupil": ""
},
{
  "School": "",
  "Class": "",
  "Pupil": ""
},
```

However, I would ideally like it returned nested like the following

```
[
    {
        School: "Name",
        Class: [
            ClassName: '',
            Pupil: [
                    PupilName: ''},
                    PupilName: ''},
                    PupilName: '']

    },
    {
        School: "Name",
        Class: [
            ClassName: '',
            Pupil: [
                    PupilName: ''},
                    PupilName: ''},
                    PupilName: '']

    },
```

I may have butchered that but you get the general idea.

The class for the data again is very simple

```
public class Area
{
    public string School { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Pupil { get; set; }
  
}
```

So far I have tried returning a list in a list etc, but without any luck.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share the ``area`` class and ``row``?, you could change the structure of area class.

Comment: Ive added the class as it is, happy to change the structure, I have attempted but unsuccessfully

Comment: maybe you could change the sql query or `returnedlist`. group by school and by class to build new list of expected object.

Answer (score 2):

To get the expected result, you could create class with this structure :

1 - Classes

```
public class NewArea
{
    public string School { get; set; }
    public List<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Pupils { get; set; }
}
```

2 - First, *group by* **school** and for each grouped item, *group by* **class**:

```
List<NewArea> newAreas = returnedlist
    .GroupBy(x => x.School)
    .Select(x => new NewArea
    {
        School = x.Key,
        Classes = x.GroupBy(y => y.Class).Select(z => new Class
        {
            Name = z.Key,
            Pupils = z.Select(w => w.Pupil).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

3 - Example for test :

```
List<Area> returnedlist = new List<Area>
{
    new Area{School = "s1", Class="c1",Pupil="p1"},
    new Area{School = "s1", Class="c1",Pupil="p2"},
    new Area{School = "s1", Class="c2",Pupil="p1"},
    new Area{School = "s1", Class="c2",Pupil="p2"},
    new Area{School = "s2", Class="c1",Pupil="p1"},
};
```

**Result**

```
[
   {
      "School":"s1",
      "Classes":[
         {
            "Name":"c1",
            "Pupils":[
               "p1",
               "p2"
            ]
         },
         {
            "Name":"c2",
            "Pupils":[
               "p1",
               "p2"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "School":"s2",
      "Classes":[
         {
            "Name":"c1",
            "Pupils":[
               "p1"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Namespaces :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: Its throwing up the following error.      'NewArea' does not contain a definition for 'Class' and no accessible extension method 'Class' accepting a first argument of type 'NewArea' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @MichaelCole i don't how you have used my code, but it's work fine for me, check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bel5i3. have you add new classes `NewArea` and `Class` to your project?.